# Proper way to override function in php

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I call PHP parent methods from within an inherited method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265351/how-do-i-call-php-parent-methods-from-within-an-inherited-method)

I am trying to override a function in php in the following way

**main class**

```
<?php    
class Curl{
   /* constructor */
   public function Curl(){}

   /* login */
   public function login($url, $post_fields){
      ...
   }
}
?>
```

**sub-class**

```
<?php
require_once("/var/www/api/curl/curl.php");

class Curl_B extends Curl{
   /* constructor */
   public function Curl_B(){}

   /* login */
   public function login(){
      $this->login(
        'https://xxx.co.uk/login.php', 
        'email=xxx&pass=xxx'
      );
   }
}

$curl = new Curl_B();
$curl->login();

?>
```

The issue is that I cannot seem to call the parent function login() properly if the sub-class has a function with the same name.

I understand that you can not have functions which share the same name so what is the best best solution to my problem?

Comment: Btw, using the class name as the constructor function is php4 era code; you should start using the `__construct()` declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call the parent class's function by the same name:

```
class Curl_B extends Curl{
   /* constructor */
   public function Curl_B(){}

   /* login */
   public function login(){
      parent::login(
        'https://xxx.co.uk/login.php', 
        'email=xxx&pass=xxx'
      );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Use Parent keyword Insted](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) You should change :

```
$this->login(
```

To

```
parent::login(
```

[PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php)

> Instead of using the literal name of the base class in your code, you should be using the special name parent, which refers to the name of your base class as given in the extends declaration of your class.