# Conditionally override a method in PHP

Tags: php, oop, overriding

Suppose I have a simple class as

```
class Master {  
    public $variable;
    public function a_method() {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

and a child class that overrides the parent method

```
class Child extends Master {
    public function a_method() {
        // some other code
    }
}
```

Now, instantiating the `Child` class with `$child_object = new Child()`, if I call the method `$child_object->a_method()` of course the overridden code will be executed. What if I conditionally want the parent method to be called instead of the child's one, depending (for example) on the value of `$child_object->variable`, but expressing the condition only inside `Master::a_method()`? In simple terms, I want something like

```
class Master {
    public $variable;
    public function a_method() {
        if ($this->variable) {
            // execute the child's method if you are in an inherited scope
        } else {
            // some code here
        }
    }
}
```

I know that acting on the child's method that would be trivial, calling `parent::a_method()` inside the conditional block, but I want the child's method to be blind to that condition.

Comment: This sounds like a very broken abstraction.  You're trying to create a dependency on the child class within the parent class, which is not a good idea.  (The parent class should have no knowledge of the child class, let alone a dependency on it.)  Depending on the problem you're trying to solve, I imagine there's a pattern that addresses it.  Maybe you want the parent/children types (which should be polymorphically indistinguishable in this case) to be supplied by a factory on another object, and the conditional should be on *that* object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call PHP parent methods from within an inherited method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265351/how-do-i-call-php-parent-methods-from-within-an-inherited-method)

Comment: The answer in the dupe should shows how to invoke the parent copy of an overriden method.

Comment: Why exactly do you feel you need to express the condition only inside `Master::a_method`? That's probably important.

Comment: Because I'm working on a framework, and that's for easiness of configuration. The fact is that `Master` class is defined internally to the framework, and who uses this framework should obtain the desired behavior without writing the conditional code (at least, that's what I would like to achieve).

Answer (score 0):

You're doing two different things based on the value of a variable. I'd suggest splitting those two things into separate methods, then you don't have to worry about overlapping names and you can extend each individually in the child classes. Something like this:

```
class Master
{
    public $var;
    public function method()
    {
        if ($this->var) {
            $this->trueMethod();
        } else {
            $this->falseMethod();
        }
    }
    protected function trueMethod() { }
    protected function falseMethod() { }
}

class Child extends Master
{
    protected function trueMethod()
    {
    }   
}
```

I.e., in your case, when $var is false, you never want to run the child code. So, split the code that gets run when $var is false into its own method, and don't override it in the child.